# Experience is valid or not

Tags: work-experience

I am working in an unregistered firm for the last six months. I get a salary but my PF is not deducted as the company is not registered. Now I am planning to go for MBA. So my doubt is whether my experience at an unregistered firm will be counted or not. Is it ok to hide this experience as it can create problems during background verification in big MNCs?

Comment: what country is this? The use of the term experience implies this is India. Please specify the country.

Comment: I understand MBA (Masters in Business Administration) and MNC (Multi National Companies). I don't understand "PF", please clarify (pro tip: try to keep at minimum the use of acronyms)

Comment: What is an unregistered firm?

Comment: you're getting paid under the table?

Comment: Also be aware of possible tax-issues for you & your _'employer'_

Comment: @DarkSygnus It could be a provident fund?

Answer (score 2):

Any work experience is work experience.

You worked for an organisation and personally grew by the experience. Work experience is not mandatorily achieved by a registered company. Associations, foundations, NGOs, etc.. are all forms of the organisation of human work and count towards work experience.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the experience is beneficial to the position you are now seeking it will add to your skills. As far as the organization not being listed there must be some ones number you can give to verify your working status.